# Does LPF limit the maximum sampling frequency of the input signal?

Tags: frequency-spectrum, sampling, frequency, lowpass-filter, frequency-domain

Consider the system where the signal passes through analog LPF with cutoff frequency of **50 Hz**, so the **maximum sampling frequency** of the input signal could be **100 Hz** (according to the [theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem)). But can I use rectangular signals with sampling frequencies higher than **100 Hz**? for example, **240 Hz**:
[image]
here is the picture of sampling frequencies spectrum and corresponding sidebands: the maximum frequency (set by LPF) is **100 Hz**, actual sampling frequency (of my rectangular signal) - **240 Hz**, left sideband - 240-100=**140 Hz**, right sideband - 240+100=**340 Hz**.

will I see such rectangular signal after passing LPF?

Comment: What do you mean by "rectangular signals?" From your picture it *looks* like you mean a bandpass signal between 140 and 340 Hz. But many will assume you mean an actual rectangle function in the time domain, which as Hilmar points out is not a bandlimited signal.

Comment: @Gillespie, in my post I tried to show the sampling frequencies and its sidebands, sorry if it looks confusing(( my main point is the following: on the one hand, LPF limits the maximum sampling frequency of incoming signal, but on the other hand - I can use rectangular signal at "any" sampling frequency in such system, my question is why?
by rectangular signals I meant just constant line of some duration (simple rectangular-shaped signal)

Comment: I think you need to edit your question and clarify it. First, by "maximum sampling frequency," I think you just mean the maximum frequency represented in the signal after the LPF? This would be 50 Hz in your example. The *minimum* sampling frequency you would need to represent this signal digitally would be twice the max frequency in your signal, 100 Hz in your case (ideally; in reality you probably want to sample faster than that to be safe, as Hilmar points out).

Comment: As for a rectangular signal, it is not bandlimited. The corners of the rectangle don't roll off smoothly, so they are high frequency. The Fourier Transform of a rectangle is a sinc, which is not bandlimited: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/fourier-transform-of-rectangular-function. So no, you can't sample a rectangle at "any" frequency you want.

Comment: but according to Hilmar's post I can use "as high as I want" sampling frequency for rectangular signal...

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by “maximum frequency” and yet you give the units of Sa/s? Frequency is usually measured in hertz (Hz). Can you clarify that you mean by “actual sampling frequency”? It *seems* like your signal is bandlimited to 100Hz and the sampling rate is 240 samples per second (Hz). But the way it’s asked makes this very unclear. Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: @PeterK., I added some edits according to your remarks: maximum frequency is the frequency that can pass the system without aliasing (here it is limited by LPF if I understand it correctly), actual sampling frequency - the frequency I'd like to use for my rectangular signal, which is higher than maximum frequency, is it clear know?

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean by "rectangular signal", but I think it's clear enough to be reopened.

Comment: as for rectangular signal I just mean some constant value of a fixed duration (it looks like rectangle - rectangular-shaped signal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still confused by what you're actually getting at, so I thought I'd try to illustrate what you're saying to see if it matches what you mean.

Suppose we have a "rectangular" signal which I'd call a square wave or a pulse train.

```
import numpy as np

N = 1000 # sample count
P = 100  # period
D = 50   # width of pulse
sig = np.arange(N) % P < D

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.plot(sig)
plt.title('Square wave')
```

which looks like

[image: Unfiltered square wave]

This has the following spectrum.

[image: Spectrum of square wave]

Let's assume that this square wave is sampled at 240Hz so that 100 samples is one period. This makes the frequency of the square wave is 2.4Hz.

Let's design a filter that has the start of the stop band at 50Hz.

```
# Design a filter with a stop band start at 50Hz.
from scipy import signal

Nlpf = 6
Wn = 30
b, a = signal.butter(Nlpf, Wn, btype='low', analog=False, output='ba', fs=240)
w, H_lpf = signal.freqz(b, a, fs=240*2*np.pi)
plt.plot(w/2/np.pi, 20 * np.log10(abs(H_lpf)))
plt.plot([50,50], [-350,10])
plt.ylim([-100,10])
plt.title('Butterworth Low Pass Filter')
```

[image: Frequency response of low pass filter]

If we filter the square wave with this filter we get the following signal and associated spectrum.

```
sig_lpf = signal.lfilter(b,a,sig)
plt.plot(sig_lpf)
plt.title('Square wave, low pass filtered')
```

[image: Low pass filtered square wave]

```
w2, h_lpf_f = signal.freqz(sig_lpf, 1, fs=240*2*np.pi)
plt.plot(w2/2/np.pi, 20 * np.log10(abs(h_lpf_f)))
plt.title("Spectrum of low pass filtered square wave")
```

[image: Spectrum of low pass filtered square wave.]

The actual sampling frequency I've used (240Hz) never enters into the spectrum plots, because the only valid range (for real-valued signals) is 0 to 120 Hz.  The "side bands" that you plot don't have any real meaning.

Can you please explain what I'm missing?

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer) just a few moments to clarify what I exactly mean: I don't exactly need square wave, I called my test signal as **rectangular**, because I'd like to see the output for different durations of **rectangular** signal or just a **pulse**, let's call it **pulse** if it is more clear for you) but my main point was - if LPF limits the maximum sampling frequency of incoming signal, does it mean that I can't sample my input signal with the frequency higher than LPF limit? from your answer I see that I can, my question is why?

Comment: @Curious As Hilmar said in this answer: `There is no "maximum sample rate". You can make it as high as you want (or can afford). The sampling theorem establishes the "minimum sample rate" required to avoid aliasing.`. Why might you want to sample at a higher rate?  Perhaps to get more accuracy for other measurements. Working at the minimum possible sampling rate is generally not a good idea if the problem needs signals of frequencies up to the limit.

Comment: ok, I don't mind) but what does the LPF limit in this case? isn't it the sampling rate of incoming signal? if I try to use sinusoidal incoming signal of 110 Hz, will I see aliasing? I think it is exactly the point I'm confused of.

Comment: If your sampling rate is 240Hz, and the sinusoid is unfiltered, then no you will not see aliasing.  If your filter is applied before sampling (so it's in the analog domain), then there will be virtually nothing at the output of a filter with a stop band that starts below 110Hz, so again no aliasing will happen but also no signal will be captured.  [Please read through Steve Smith's good book about sampling.](http://www.dspguide.com/ch3/2.htm).

Comment: I read exactly this book and my question arised from [chapter 9](http://www.dspguide.com/ch9/1.htm), where he writes "An analog low-pass filter is then used to remove all frequencies above 80 hertz, so that the signal can be digitized at 160 samples per second." - this phrase confused me, because it sounds like 160 samples per second is the highest sampling frequency I can use for input signal, but from your answers with @Hilmar I can use any sampling frequency for input signal...

Comment: @Curious In that example 160Hz is the **lowest** sample rate that can be used. You can sample as fast as you like, provided it's above the minimum.

Comment: I see, the lowest corresponds to 80 Hz (for 40 Hz I can use 80 Hz if it is the highest frequency of interest), for the first time I thought 160 Hz is the **highest** sampling rate, thanl you so much for your answer and your comments, it really helped me!)

Answer (score 1):

> Consider the system where the signal passes through analog LPF with cutoff frequency of 50 Hz, so the maximum sampling frequency of the input signal could be 100 Sa/s (according to the theorem).

No.

The sampling theorem states that the sampling rate must be higher than twice the highest frequency in your signal or you get aliasing. In your example that depends a lot on your signal and the LPF. "cutoff frequency" typically refers to the -3dB point of the filter. That means there is still plenty of energy above the cutoff frequency and you would be at risk for significant aliasing if you sample at 100Hz. There is no "maximum sample rate". You can make it as high as you want (or can afford).  The sampling theorem establishes the "minimum sample rate" required to avoid aliasing.

> But can I use rectangular signals ?

It is unclear what you are asking. A rectangular wave is not bandlimited and hence it can't be sampled without aliasing.

Comment: for rectangualr signals I just wanted to know, will I see the difference between two rectangular signals sampled at 100 Sa/s and 240 Sa/s, for example?

Comment: in your answer you write that "you would be at risk for significant aliasing if you sample at 100Hz", but in the next sentence you write "There is no "maximum sample rate". You can make it as high as you want (or can afford)", it confused me a bit, could you please clarify it?

Comment: I'm saying depending on the spectrum of your signal and the properties of your low-pass filter you should probably sample significantly higher than 100Hz. Maybe 200Hz, maybe 500Hz. It really depends on the details and how much aliasing you can tolerate

Comment: ok, here in my post I used sampling frequency for rectangular signal of 240 Sa/s and LPF filters above 50 Hz, will I see such signal after passing this LPF?

Comment: Sorry,  I still don't understand what you are asking. I would help if you could write down your signal with precise mathematical definition, like $x(t) = ???$ or $X(\omega) = ???$

Comment: ok, let it be for signal:
$\operatorname{x}(t) = \Pi(t) =
\left\{\begin{array}{rl}
 1, & \text{if } 0 < t < \frac{10}{240} \\
 0, & \text{if } t \geq \frac{10}{240}
\end{array}\right.$

sampling space $t=\frac{1}{240}$, LPF cutoff (it is not important for me whether it is at $-3dB$ level) frequency is $50 Hz$ and signal length is 20 samples, is it clear?